# What exactly does win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")?

Tags: python, windows, pywin32, win32com

I was searching for a Python piece of code which would simulate keystrokes.
I stumble upon something using `win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")`.
I am not fan (at all) of Windows but it is to help a friend with automation of a game.

I got a problem, this works fine on notepad or firefox for example, it does write but not on his game.
In order to find wether it comes from his game or my automation I would like to have some details about `win32com.client` and what really represents `WScript.Shell`

Thank you all

Comment: have you tried autoit?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Some citations:

> As we discussed previously, automation objects are COM objects that
> expose methods and properties using the IDispatch interface. So how do
> we use these objects from Python? The win32com.client package contains
> a number of modules to provide access to automation objects. This
> package supports both late and early bindings, as we will discuss.
>
> To use an IDispatch-based COM object, use the method
> win32com.client.Dispatch(). This method takes as its first parameter
> the ProgID or CLSID of the object you wish to create. If you read the
> documentation for Microsoft Excel, you'll find the ProgID for Excel is
> Excel.Application, so to create an object that interfaces to Excel,
> use the following code:

```
import win32com.client
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
```

(from [this](http://www.cesarkallas.net/arquivos/apostilas/python/doc/Python%20Programming%20on%20Win32_%20Chapter%2012%20Advanced%20Python%20and%20COM.pdf))

> The WScript.Shell object provides functions to read system information
> and environment variables, work with the registry and manage
> shortcuts.
> (from: [1](http://www.pctools.com/guides/scripting/detail/109/?act=reference) [2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aew9yb99%28v=vs.84%29.aspx))

Comment: Fixed your link but if you could find an o reilly one would be best